# C++ Trying to create Gradebook with user input using arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I wanted to

1. Create the class Student. Each student has a name and a grade. Include appropriate
   member functions to manipulate student objects.
2. Replace the grades data member with students data member, which is an array of students
   of Student class. That is, you need to change 1) the type of the array from integer to
   student, and 2) the name of the array from grades to students.
3. Make GradeBook class and all its member functions work for the new type of array.**

### Gradebook.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
    #include<string>
    #include"Gradebook.h"
    #include<array>
    using namespace std;

   int main()
{
string courseName;

cout <<"Enter course name:";
cin >> courseName;
cout << "===============================Entering student information===============================" << endl;
cout <<"Enter the name and grade for 10 students"<<endl;
array<int, 10> studentGrades{ 87, 68, 94, 100, 83, 78, 85, 91, 76, 87 };
    GradeBook myGradeBook(courseName,studentGrades);

    myGradeBook.setCourseName(courseName);

    myGradeBook.processGrades();


}
```

### Gradebook.h

```
#pragma once

    #include<string>
    #include<array>

    class GradeBook {
    public:

GradeBook(std::string& cName,std::array<int,10>& sGrades) :
    courseName{ cName }, studentGrades{ sGrades } {

}

std::string getCourseName() const {
    return courseName;
}

void setCourseName(const std::string& cName) {
    courseName = cName;

}

void processGrades() const {
    outputGrades();
    std::cout << "\nClass average: " << getAverage() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nClass maximum: " << getMaximum() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\nClass minimum: " << getMinimum() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Bar Chart:\n";
    outputBarChart();
}

int getMaximum() const {
    int highGrade{ 0 };

    //range-based for loop
    for (int grade : studentGrades) {
        if (highGrade < grade) {
            highGrade = grade;
        }
    }
enter code here
    return highGrade;
}

int getMinimum() const {
    int lowGrade{ 100 };

    for (int grade : studentGrades) {
        if (lowGrade > grade) {
            lowGrade = grade;
        }
    }
    return lowGrade;
}

double getAverage() const {
    int sum{ 0 };
    for (int grade : studentGrades) {
        sum += grade;
    }
    return static_cast<double>(sum) / studentGrades.size();

}

void outputGrades() const {
    std::cout << "\n The grades are: \n\n";

    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < studentGrades.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout <<"Student #"<< i + 1 << " grade: "<< studentGrades.at(i) << std::endl;
    }

}
void outputBarChart() const {
    std::cout << "\nGrade distribution:\n";
    std::array<int, 11> frequency{};

    for (int grade : studentGrades) {
        ++frequency[grade / 10];
    }

    for (size_t i{ 0 }; i < frequency.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i == 0) {
            std::cout << "  0-9:";
        }
        else if (i == 10) {
            std::cout << "  100:";
        }
        else {
                std::cout << i * 10 << "-" << (i*10) + 9 << ":";
        }

        for (unsigned stars{ 0 }; stars < frequency[i]; ++stars) {
            std::cout << '*';
        }

       std::cout << std::endl;
        
    }

}

    private:
std::string courseName;
std::array<int, 10> studentGrades;
std::array<int, 10> studentNames;
    };
```

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjh3v.png)

Comment: Is using arrays a requirement?  Using `std::vector` would be a lot easier.

Comment: What's your question / issue?

Comment: What part of the assignment are you having issues with?

Comment: also attached I have a picture of the desired output

Comment: Don't paste code in comments, the code is unreadable.  Edit your post with the text of your code and format accordingly.

Comment: Don't paste output as picture.  Highlight the output text, copy to the clipboard, then paste into your question as text.  Pictures can be difficult to read based on the viewer (such as mobile phones, or notebooks).  Text scales a lot better than pictures and takes up less space (on storage devices).

Comment: I recommend you create a separate class for a student, that contains the name and grade.  The Grade Book, then becomes a container of Students, such as `std::vector<Student>` or `std::array<Student>`.

Comment: what about the user input???

Comment: Usually User input is covered in the first chapters of a good C++ book.  See `std::cin` and `std::getline`.

Answer (score 0):

The secret is in the encapsulation of functionality in the `Student` class:

```
class Student
{
  std::string m_name;
  std::vector<int> m_grades;
  public:
    void input_with_prompt();
};

void Student::input_with_prompt()
{
  std::cout << "Enter Student Name: ";
  std::getline(std::cin, name);
  std::cout << "Enter 10 grades:\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
     int grade;
     std::cin >> grade;
     m_grades.push_back(grade);
  }
}
```

You could use this in the `main` function or elsewhere as:

```
Student s;
s.input_with_prompt();
```

You can also augment the `Student` class with `min, max,` and `avg` methods.  This will help out with the Grade Book class:

```
std::array<Student, 10> grade_book;
Student s;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  s.input_with_prompt();
  grade_book[i] = s;
}
int min = grade_book[0].minimum_grade();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
  int min_grade = grade_book[i].minimum_grade();
  if (min > min_grade) min = min_grade;
}
```

The maximum and average functionalities can be implemented in a similar manner.
This is one implementation.  There are many others.